# Should I get an Intuos pro medium or large, when used to A4 paper?

Tags: drawing-tablet, hardware-recommendation

I am used to a A4 paper of course. I have already saved up for the medium sized Intuos, but the large (if you do the match) is cheaper for its size.

I don't know which to buy, should I save up *even* more money for the large because of the math and more work space, or will it feel a little too big if I am used to A4, hard to move around and so on? I don't know, my income also isn't that big BTW.

What version should I get?

Comment: Hi BlackLips, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. It seems to me your question is mainly opinion-based, so I voted to close it. Opinion-based questions are off-topic on this site. If you want to know more about what is off-topic and on, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I've emphasised the criteria of being used to A4, which is what makes this not just about opinion.

Comment: This is really just a matter of preference and no one can decide for you. I prefer the large, especially after working with a 8x6 [medium] (close to A4) for years.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is, if you're most comfortable with A4, the medium Intuos Pro is already pretty darn large. It's almost A3 - the drawing area is almost as tall as a portrait A4 sheet and wider than a landscape A4 sheet.

The "large" is more comparable in size to an old-school drafting desk.

If you're most comfortable with A4 drawing, I'd say go medium. Unless you're most comfortable sitting at a drafting desk, large is likely to feel huge!]

---

Just incase anyone is unfamiliar with drafting desks, I mean like this ([image source](http://img.archiexpo.com/images_ae/photo-g/drafting-table-67258-6326835.jpg)). Popular among architects, technical illustrators, etc. Very different to drawing in an A4 sketchbook.

[image]